# Core Data: Access linked entity attributes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity called "Expense" which is linked to another one called "Trip".
How can I access the trip linked to each expense?

[image]

I'm working with NSManagedObjects, so as an example, here one of my methods:

```
  func fillCellWithExpense(cell: DayExpensesViewCell, expense: NSManagedObject) -> DayExpensesViewCell {
    let amount = expense.value(forKey: AMOUNT) as! Double
    cell.amountLabel?.text = String(format:"%.2f", amount)
    let category = expense.value(forKey: CATEGORY) as! String
    cell.categoryLabel?.text = category
    switch category {

    case "Transportation":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C1
    case "Shopping":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C2
    case "Food":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C3
    case "Accomodation":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C4
    case "Fun":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C5
    case "Coffee":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C6
    case "Groceries":
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C7
    default:
      cell.line.backgroundColor = Colors.C8
    }

return cell
}
```

If I would like to access an expense trip's name, can I simply cast the NSManagedObject to Expense and then access it's attributes?

```
let e = expense as! Expense
e.trip.value(forKey: "name")
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model editor, you need to add a relationship and its inverse to both models (which it looks like you've *at least* partially done).

If I'm guessing your model correctly, set a to-one relationship on Expense to Trip (call it trip). Set a to-many relationship on Trip to Expense (maybe call it expenses), and set its inverse to the relationship you made on Expense (called trip).

Then, if your target is Swift, you can access `trip` on each `Expense`; e.g. ...

`var expense = Expense()
expense.trip // ...`

Comment: I see. But... what about if I'm working with NSManagedObjects?
(I'm editing the question)

Comment: @gmoraleda My example was actually with NsManagaedObjects, just the actual type (eg Expense), not the superclass. In your updated example, if you know you have an Expense then *yes* you can just cast it.